# SWIFT - How to fix a callback occurring too late

Tags: ios, swift, callback, completionhandler

I'm making a networking call, getting data back and would like to put that data to use in a tableVC by providing data to a var in the tableVC. The problem I'm encountering is that my callback is returning the data too late. below is my code. I'd really appreciate any suggestions

Code from network manager

```
  func getArticles(completion: @escaping PListCompletion) {

        guard let url = plistUrlString else { return }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        let defaultConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: defaultConfig)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let data = data {
                    let articles = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Articles].self, from: data)
                    self.callBackOnMainThread(completion: completion, response: .success(response: PlistResponseData(results: articles)))
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
                completion(.failure(error: error))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    private func callBackOnMainThread(completion: @escaping PListCompletion, response: PlistResponse) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(response)
        }
    }
```

```
final class ArticleListProvider {

     var articles: [Articles]

    convenience init() {
        self.init(articles: [])

        self.provideArticles { (article) in
            self.articles.append(contentsOf: article)
        }
    }

    init(articles: [Articles]) {
        self.articles = articles
    }

    func articleCount() -> Int {
//used for tableVC cells but returning 0
        return self.articles.count
    }

    func articleAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> Articles? {
        return articles[index]
    }

    func provideArticles(completion: @escaping ([Articles]) -> Void) {
        ArticleDetailsNetworkManager.sharedInstance.getArticles { [weak self] (response) in
            guard let weakSelf = self else { return}
            switch response {
            case .success(let plistData):
                weakSelf.articles = plistData.results
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            completion(weakSelf.articles)
        }
    }
}
```

tableVC

```
final class ArticleListController: UITableViewController {
    fileprivate let CellIdentifier = "Cell"

    fileprivate let articleListProvider: ArticleListProvider

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
        self.articleListProvider = ArticleListProvider()
        super.init(style:style)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.articleListProvider = ArticleListProvider()
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTableViewCell()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ArticleListController {

    func setupTableViewCell() {
        tableView.register(ArticleTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

//this is returning 0 when it should be returning the amount of articles from the articleProvider, where the networking call is being made 

        return articleListProvider.articleCount()
    }
```

I don't know if this matters, but this worked on Xcode 9.4, (though w/o the callback), this problem occurred after upgrading to 10.1

Answer (score 3):

It's a desired behavior, the api call is asynchronous and it won't return anything immediately. Because of that the array count will be zero until that web-service returns a result.

Change your init method like:

```
convenience init(callback: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.init(articles: [])

    self.provideArticles { (article) in
        self.articles.append(contentsOf: article)
        callback()
    }
}
```

And use it from your view controller in the following way:

```
self.articleListProvider = ArticleListProvider{ [weak self]
    guard let weakSelf = self else { return}
    weakSelf.yourTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful - thanks! I also had to declare my articleListProvider property as optional in order for this to work.